# Ending a for cycle after an if construct has been executed ONCE

Tags: php

I'm new to the community, I hope I'm not doing anything wrong.
So, I'm trying to develop a Turing machine simulator. I want to exit a `for` construct after the `if` construct (which is inside the `for`) is executed **ONCE**. Is there an easy way to do it or I do have to redo all the coding?

Comment: Use a `break` statement to exit any kind of loop.

Comment: Does [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` statement will terminate the execution of the current loop it is in. For example:

```
<?php

    $array = [4,3,5,2,0,4];
    $count = count($array);

    for($i=0; $i <$count; $i++)
    {
        if($i == 5)
        {
            break;    // This terminates the current FOR or WHILE loop
        }
    }
?>
```

If you have a nested environment like a `FOR` loop inside another `FOR` loop then you need a `break` for each of them to completely terminate the loops.

```
<?php
    while(someStatement)             
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
        {
            if($i == 5)
            {
                 break;
            }
        }
        // This gets executed after the break above
        // To stop the WHILE prematurely you will need another break here
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, solved.

Comment: I think i did it.